# Backlight adjustment not working in Lenovo IdeaPad Y580

Tags: 13.04, lenovo, backlight

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Y580, and I added the `acpi_backlight=vendor` option to the bootloader. The OS boots without the black screen now, but I can't adjust the brightness with Fn+Up/Down keys. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright solved this on my own.

1. Open file `/etc/default/grub`.
2. Find a line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` (there might be something between the quotes).
3. Add `acpi_osi=Linux` between the quotes, so the result might be something like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`
4. Run `sudo update-grub`